# NUCLEO stm32L053R8 can't set any port bit high/low at a register level

Tags: arm, stm32, microcontroller, gpio

I have been working on setting a port bit high for at least 8 hours now and am at a loss. I am using the NUCLEO stm32L053R8 dev board on the Keil IDE. I have read the reference manual in the gpio section many times for the L0 series and I have attempted many different approaches to manipulating the registers. I am using the ST-LINK/V2-1 on the dev board of course. Here is my code for context. I am wondering if it isn't my code at all but my development environment. I have also tried different ports to see if I accidentally messed up Port A itself. I am able to flash the blinky program so I know it isn't an uploading problem.

Here is my code:

#include "stm32l053xx.h"

int main(void) {

```
RCC->IOPENR |= RCC_IOPENR_IOPAEN;
GPIO->MODER = 0xEBFFFCFF;
GPIO->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE3_0;

while(1) {
    
    GPIO->BSSR = GPIO_BSRR_BS_3;
}
```

}

According to the L0 reference manual that is the value to clear the Port A modes ^. From there I set the bit as an output. I noticed that the stm32Fxxx series' use a different register to start the GPIO clock. I apologize if I am missing any relevant information for someone to help me, it's been a long day.

Comment: you only write the bssr register once, writing the same value over and over again does nothing.

Comment: the way you are doing the moder has both issues and can be done cleaner  x = moder;  moder &= (~(biits you want to clear));  x|= bits you want to set;  moder = x;  one change to the register not more than one

Comment: it is possible depending on the compiler and dumb luck to have a race condition from the write to iopenr and moder such that the write to moder is too soon and does not take.  For some strange reason, my experiments show that if you do a write to iopenr (str) and then a read from moder (ldr) back to back it works with the read of moder being the first step in the read, mask, modify, write

Comment: Please post the disassembly of this section to see if you have created a race condition.

Comment: also understand that if this is an led, some board designs you drive the pin high to turn the led on, some you drive the pin low to turn the led, check the schematics or the board documentation.

Comment: assume every different stm32 part uses a different address map for gpio, etc.  ST has at least two different gpio logic blocks for stm32 parts so just configuring the gpio is different.  the clock enable registers can vary in more than two ways from one stm32 chip to another.  Use the appropriate datasheet and reference manual for the part in question.